# Can we edit the classic AJAX-reload script to return the value in a textbox instead of a div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I set the returned value to be added as a value of a textbox instead of a div ?
for example `<input type="text" id="link" name="link" value="HERE" />`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script language='JavaScript'>
setInterval( 'SANAjax();', 1000 );

$(function() {
SANAjax = function(){

$('#dataDisplay').load('yourfile.php');

}
 });
</script>
<div id="dataDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get("yourfile.php", function(data){
    $("#link").val(data);
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
var SANAjax = function(){
    $.get("yourfile.php", function(data){
        $("#link").val(data);
        setTimeout(SANAjax, 1000);
    }).fail(function(){
        setTimeout(SANAjax, 1000);
    });
};

$(function(){
    SANAjax();
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. Can you please edit my code? What should I put on value="" to echo the value ?

Comment: That's what my code does - it gets the data from `yourfile.php` and puts that data into the `value` of the input...

Comment: Excuse me but can you be more specific? Do I need to combine the two parts or should i put yours into value="your code here" ?

Comment: Replace your code with the one in my answer edit. Also you need to be using the latest version of jQuery - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: It worked just great! Thank you very much! 1000 is 1 sec right ?

Comment: Yep...1000 milliseconds are equal to a second.